# problems in checking login form

Tags: php, sql, login-script

I do not know why php ignore the if statement and it does not perform the check,

```
    <?php
   require 'default.php';
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      $username = stripslashes($username);
      $password = stripslashes($password);
      $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
      if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'"))==1
         && mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `password`='$password'"))==1){
          echo 'you Have logged in successfully';
         }else{
             echo 'Incorrect username or password had been entered!';
            }
   }

?>
```

Comment: What will happend it there are two same passwords in your table? It won't work. You should firstly refactor it to use one database query.

Comment: What have you tried? And also what `if` statement are you referring too? Double check your variable names are correct. You can use `print_r($_REQUEST);` to make sure you are getting some sort of request through on this script.

Comment: Good point @des: `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";`

Comment: Please DO HASH YOUR PASSWORDS, do not store them in plaintext. There is an easy to use solution: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat until we wait for PHP5.5 to arrive.

Answer (score 3):

#### What if one user has the supplied username and another user has supplied password? It logs in?

Please change your code this way:

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'"))==1)
```

Comment: @des Sorry, didn't note. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem, no need to be sorry ;)

Answer (score -1):

the mysql_num_rows() may return value more than 1, may be?

```
<?php
require 'default.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  if (
    mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' LIMIT 0,1"))==1
    &&
    mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `password`='$password' LIMIT 0,1"))==1
  ) {
    echo 'you Have logged in successfully';
  }
  else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or password had been entered!';
  }
}

?>
```

or use > 0 instead.

```
<?php
require 'default.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  if (
  mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username'")) > 0
  &&
  mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `password`='$password'")) > 0
  ) {
    echo 'you Have logged in successfully';
  }
  else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or password had been entered!';
  }
}

?>
```

Or make it simple this way...

```
<?php
require 'default.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  if (intval(mysql_result(mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) AS found FROM `users` WHERE `username`='%s' AND `password`='%s'",$username,$password)),0)) > 0 ) {
    echo 'you Have logged in successfully';
  }
  else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or password had been entered!';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: When username and password is unique, how can there be more than one?

Comment: If you try to fix the code, why don't you fix the security hole with the separate queries?

Comment: Had you try to echo the mysql_num_rows(), and verify the number returned from it? It is ok to use "> 0", when login is incorrect, it always return zero.

Comment: @DannyHong What are you trying to do here?

Comment: `sprintf` inside `mysql_query()` function? **Excellent!**